# Marklogic - How to know fields/elements have been indexes

Tags: marklogic

The ErrorLog.txt shows one of indexes is not found on field.  But it shows field index names on admin Gui and also admin:database-get-range-field-indexes().  Is there a way to know for sure fields have been indexes or not been indexes.  Thanks.

Error Log:

```
2019-03-13 10:11:40 Notice:MdrRestServer: XDMP-FIELD XDMP-FIEDLRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:field-reference("bay","type=string")..No string field range index for bay http://marklogic.com/collation/
2019-03-13 10:11:40 Notice:MdrRestServer: in /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-imp.xyq, at 4335:14
2019-03-13 10:11:40Notice:MdrRestServer: in impl:range-reference(<search:range type = "xs:string" facet="true" xmlns:search="http://MarkLogic/appsearch/search"></search:range[1.0-ml] )
```

Comment: Post the relevant portion of the error log and code causing the error.

Comment: What collation is listed in the admin ui, and which one are you specifying in your search?

Comment: I have reindex again and see "bay" field is starting index. That telling me what I see on admin Gui range-field-index on display doesn't guarantee it has been indexed.  How can I check to be sure it already index.